# Could not write bytes: broken pipe - looking for log of removed packages

Tags: boot, command-line, gedit

I have a dual boot system with 12.04 and windows 7. Ubuntu worked fine yesterday but this morning upon boot I get subject. Searched the forums and unsuccessful with recovery. I tried :

`sudo gedit /var/log/apt/history.log`

To see the log of removed packages, but get the following:

```
** (gedit:976): WARNING **: Command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=2d7d18532e9953bc8a2b852e00000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Cannot open display:
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

Anyone have any suggestions for a fix? Please let me know if you require any additional information.

Problem solved. 1. Go to recovery mode / 2. In recovery mode Enable Networking / 3. In recovery mode select Drop to Shell / 4. In shell sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg / 5. In shell dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg / 6. Exit bash and return to recovery menu, select normal boot. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. M

Comment: try `sudo nano /var/log/apt/history.log` . or you could run `history` command.

Comment: Thank you. I get the GNU nano screen but really can't identify the packages. Are they listed next to "Upgrade"?

Comment: To clarify, my Pc has an NVIDIA card which I make use of using Bumblebee. Not sure if this may be the problem and reason I'm not booting. Thanks again for any assistance.

Comment: did you install nvidia drivers? if yes then run `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Now reboot your pc. Still you can't able to login then remove all the packages which are related to nvidia by running `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*` command.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no luck. I get...

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/etc/x11/xorg.conf' : No such file or directory

Comment: Additionally on boot I no longer get the notice "could not write bytes: broken pipes". I get a solid non blinking cursor at the top left of the screen. Thoughts?

Comment: Problem solved. 1. Go to recovery mode / 2. In recovery mode Enable Networking / 3. In recovery mode select Drop to Shell / 4. In shell sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg / 5. In shell dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg / 6. Exit bash and return to recovery menu, select normal boot. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. M

Comment: post the above comment as an answer.

Comment: For some reason clicking "answer your question" does not work. Answer in my initial post. Regret the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^Remove/' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

That'll show you the most recently removed packages, oldest in the log will be first. Histories are archived over time so you might find you need to check older files (I have 12 numbered archives) to check the first:

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz | awk '/^Remove/'
```

Or you can do them all at once:

```
zgrep -E --color '^Remove' /var/log/apt/history*
```

I'm not sure if that could ever be that useful though as it's probably going to show you way too much information.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try when I get home from work.

Comment: Your are right... show WAY too much information. Stuck.